# SQL use value from CASE EXISTS

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgres 9.5.3

A fragment from a bigger query which updates a JSONB field in a different table (I don't think the JSONB stuff has any relevance to the question however):

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT role FROM people WHERE result_id = r2.id AND admin = 't')
THEN (elem || jsonb_build_object('admin', true, 'role', role))
ELSE (elem - 'admin' - 'role')
END
```

Essentially if the record exists, I want to be able to use the value of the `role` field from that record.

As it currently is written, we get an error `column "role" does not exist`

Comment: Please show the complete query. But you probably want an outer join from your main query to the `people` table.

Comment: Try `coalesce((SELECT elem || jsonb_build_object('admin', true, 'role', role) FROM people WHERE result_id = r2.id AND admin = 't'), elem - 'admin' - 'role')` instead of `case ...`.

Comment: @Abelisto This worked, thank you.

Comment: You'd better be certain that the subquery will only return a single row.

Answer (score 0):

if you expect `(SELECT role FROM people WHERE result_id = r2.id AND admin = 't')` to provide attribute `role` for `THEN` and `ELSE`, it won't.

sample:

```
b=# create table people (result_id int,admin text, role text);
CREATE TABLE
b=# insert into people select 1,'t','one';
INSERT 0 1
b=# create table r2 (id int,elem jsonb);
CREATE TABLE
b=# insert into r2 select 1,'{"admin":false}';
INSERT 0 1
b=#  select CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT role FROM people WHERE result_id = r2.id AND admin = 't')
b-# THEN (elem || jsonb_build_object('admin', true, 'role', role))
b-# ELSE (elem - 'admin' - 'role')
b-# END from r2;
ERROR:  column "role" does not exist
LINE 2: ...EN (elem || jsonb_build_object('admin', true, 'role', role))
                                                                 ^
b=# alter table r2 add column role text;
ALTER TABLE
b=#  select CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT role FROM people WHERE result_id = r2.id AND admin = 't')
THEN (elem || jsonb_build_object('admin', true, 'role', role))
ELSE (elem - 'admin' - 'role')
END from r2;
             case
-------------------------------
 {"role": null, "admin": true}
(1 row)
```